# Deleted objects appear when Appending model

Tags: error, append

I've been having this strange issue since I started using Blender, and I cannot find any information about it anywhere online.

The issue is, whenever I append a model into another file, it Appends objects that were deleted in the original file, such as the base shapes used for custom bone shapes. And for some of my models, even random armatures that never existed in the base file.

It's not a huge issue, but it's getting annoying having to delete a bunch of random shapes every time I want to Append a model into another scene.

[image]

Comment: open the original file and do a *File -> Clean Up* to remove unused data blocks.