Can I clean up invisible junk data of duplicated mesh object?
I just duplicated 100 faces of 100000 polygon mesh and separated it, but it seems this new mesh which only has 100 faces has just same amount of data of 100000 polygon mesh and If I save this file blend data size gets double. I mean 100000 polygon mesh data has 40 MB data and newly created 100 faces mesh has 40 MB too but it only has 100 faces. I don't know where this 100 faces mesh data stores junk data but I need to delete them to reduce blend file data size. Do you know how to delete this invisible junk data?

Just deleted my previous comment but: You must be doing something wrong! - I've just saved a file with just an icosphere subdivided 7 times to give 82,000 faces giving a file size of 7,202,600 bytes. Duplicating 100 faces from it, seperating them into a seperate object and then deleting the original icosphere gives a file size of 1,148,224 bytes!

OK then this happens only to me. I just need to make stickers based on the 100000 polygon mesh. I exported this stickers (100 faces mesh data) as obj and imported it and do "Link Object Data" with original 40MB 100 faces polygon mesh to restore vertex group  and UV data. And I restored modifiers too by "Copy Modifiers" .  After that I deleted  original 40MB 100 faces polygon mesh and saved blend file then that invisible 40 MB junk data is gone. I don't know where those 40 MB junk data was saved.....

The only suggestion I have is that you try deleting the unused data before saving your file as I'll show you in the answer that I'll post in a minute. However that shouldn't be saved when you save the file as long as you haven't flagged it as a Fake user.

There's also this posting: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269331/deleted-objects-appear-when-appending-model. Although it's pretty old, the answer was actually posted today so it might be worth investigating that too. Also try File > Clean Up > Purge Unused Data.

I saw the post and it happens all the time.  And I always do "Clean UP" because my project file is so huge, I need to be careful about file size of my project file. Problem is my mesh data stores invisible data somewhere for sure and It can't be deleted by Clean UP and also it can't be picked up in Outliner - Blender File.  I just duplicated faces from this 100000 polygon mesh in Edit mode and separated them and file size increases. I thought "Link Object Data" would restores this invisible junk data too but it doesn't.

No idea in that case I'm afraid.

Having duplicated and seperated a 100 face 'patch' from an Icosphere which is now Icosphere.001 and deleted the original Icosphere, you can select Unused Data from the Display Mode dropdown on the Outliner as shown below:

Open the Meshes section and you'll see that the data for the original Icosphere is still there and, if it's not been tagged with a Fake user, the shield icon on the right will be empty:

You can right-click on it and select ⌦ Delete to remove it. However, saving the file should have deleted the data automatically anyway.
